# Javascript: Removing Semi-Duplicate Objects within an Array with Conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to remove the "Duplicate" objects within an array while retaining the object that has the lowest value associated with it.

~~Original

```
var array = [
 {
   "time": "2021-11-12T20:37:11.112233Z",
   "value": 3.2
 },
 {
   "time": "2021-11-12T20:37:56.115222Z",
   "value": 3.8
 },
 {
   "time": "2021-11-13T20:37:55.112255Z",
   "value": 4.2
 },
 {
   "time": "2021-11-13T20:37:41.112252Z",
   "value": 2
 },
 {
   "time": "2021-11-14T20:37:22.112233Z",
   "value": 3.2
 }
]
```

~~Expected Output

```
var array = [
 {
   "time": "2021-11-12T20:37:11.112233Z",
   "value": 3.2
 },
 {
   "time": "2021-11-13T20:37:41.112252Z",
   "value": 2
 },
 {
   "time": "2021-11-14T20:37:22.112233Z",
   "value": 3.2
 }
]
```

What I have so far:

```
var result = array.reduce((aa, tt) => { 
    if (!aa[tt.time]) {
        aa[tt.time] = tt;
    } else if (Number(aa[tt.time].value) < Number(tt.value)) { 
        aa[tt.time] = tt;
    }
    return aa;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

I realize the issue with what I am trying to do is that the "time" attribute is not identical to the other time values I am considering as duplicates.

Though for this use case I do not need the time out to ms. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM (to the minute) is fine. I am not sure how to implement a reduction method for this case when the time isnt exactly the same. Maybe if only the first 16 characters were checked in the string?

Let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: *"to the minute is fine"*: what if the minute has 1 difference, but the time difference is really only 5 seconds? Like 45:01 and 44:59? *"Maybe if only the first 16 characters were checked in the string?"* Isn't that for you to decide? Does that yield the results you want?

Comment: Allow me to clarify.
I need to do the reduction method ignoring seconds and milliseconds. Therefore only checking the first 16 characters of the time value would indeed yield the results I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a few issues:

- If you want to only check the first 16 characters to detect a duplicate, you should use that substring of `tt.time` as key for `aa` instead of the whole string.
- Since you want the minimum, your comparison operator is wrong.
- The code produces an object, while you want an array, so you still need to extract the values from the object.

Here is your code with those adaptations:

```js
var array = [{"time": "2021-11-12T20:37:11.112233Z","value": 3.2},{"time": "2021-11-12T20:37:56.115222Z","value": 3.8},{"time": "2021-11-13T20:37:55.112255Z","value": 4.2},{"time": "2021-11-13T20:37:41.112252Z","value": 2},{"time": "2021-11-14T20:37:22.112233Z","value": 3.2}];

var result = Object.values(array.reduce((aa, tt) => { 
    var key = tt.time.slice(0, 16);
    if (!aa[key]) {
        aa[key] = tt;
    } else if (Number(aa[key].value) > Number(tt.value)) { 
        aa[key] = tt;
    }
    return aa;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. That worked perfectly. I probably should have just left it for the morning and came back to it! Really appreciate such a quick answer!